# Transform grid coordinates to ggplot coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

In my `shiny` app I create a `ggplot` graph, which I transform to a `grob` via `ggplotGrob`. (I do this because I need to fiddle with the heigths of the underlying `gtable`).

Now I want to add a `clickOpts` handler to my output to allow for some interactivity. The returned coordinates are now however in `'grid'` coordinates (`npc`?) and in order to use `nearPoints` I want to scale them back to the original coordinate system. How could I do that?

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
   plotOutput("plot", click = "click"),
   verbatimTextOutput("debug")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$plot <- renderPlot({
      pl <- qplot(mpg, disp, data = mtcars)
      grid.draw(ggplotGrob(pl))
   })

   output$debug <- renderPrint({
      req(input$click)
      cat("Coordinates in npc(?): (", input$click$x, " / ", input$click$y, ")\n", sep = "")
      cat("How tot get that to the ggplot coordinates (i.e. to mpg and disp)?")
   })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

---

**Update**

Going through CCurtis' comment, I updated my code slightly:

```
library(shiny)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 10 * (1:10), z = 1:10 + 10)

ui <- fluidPage(
   fluidRow(column(width = 3, selectInput("x", "Select x-Axis:", 
                                          choices = names(dat))), 
            column(width = 3, radioButtons("grid", "Use Grid?",
                                           choices = c("Yes", "No")))),
   plotOutput("plot", click = clickOpts("click", FALSE)),
   verbatimTextOutput("debug")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   getPlot <- reactive({
      req(input$x)
      ggplot(dat, aes_string(input$x, "y")) + geom_point() + 
         scale_y_continuous(breaks = dat$y) + 
         scale_x_continuous(breaks = dat[[input$x]])
   })
   output$plot <- renderPlot({
      if (input$grid == "Yes") {
        grid.draw(ggplotGrob(getPlot()))
      } else {
         getPlot()
      }
   })

   output$debug <- renderPrint({
      req(input$click)
      cat("Coordinates in ?: (", input$click$x, " / ", input$click$y, ")\n", 
          sep = "")
      pl <- getPlot()
      xl <- ggplot_build(pl)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$x.range
      yl <- ggplot_build(pl)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$y.range
      cat("Limits of plot: x = ", xl[1], " / ", xl[2], "\ty = ", 
          yl[1], " / ", yl[2], "\n", sep = "") 
      trans <- function(x, y) y[1] + diff(y) * x
      cat("Coordinates in native: (", trans(input$click$x, xl), " / ", 
                                      trans(input$click$y, yl), ")\n", sep = "")
   })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

However, when playing with the code I observed that the coordinates `(0/0)` and `(1/1)` are apparently **not** at the bottom left and the top right corner of the plot panel but slightly outside. Hence, I was wondering which coordinates does `input$click` actually report? Are this indeed `npc` coordinates but the origin of the coordinate system does not coincide with the origin of the plot panel?

Things work very smoothly when you use the `ggplot`object directly as you can see in the example.

Comment: Sorry forgot the `ggplot2`library - fixed now.

Comment: Ya, just deleted my last comment, typo forgot the 2 on ggplot2. Your code works for me now.

Comment: I'm at work so I can't go through the all the trouble but since the "NPC" unit is just a normalized unit for the viewpoint if you know the dimension of the viewport in the mpg units then you can back calculate the position on the screen knowing your npc units. I.e. on my screen the max x axis is 35 the max y axis is about 600. So if my mouse is on 1,1 (npc) that coordinate is 35,600 (mpg/disp). You should be able to look into `ggplot` to determine how it sets the xlim/ylim, or you can just fix the them yourself. Once you know the ylim/xlim you can convert your units.